# How can I show custom attribute value as menu item label in magento 2?

Tags: magento, magento2

I have created a custom attribute for menu title on category add/edit page in my magento 2 setup. I want to show the value of the attribute saved in database instead of the category title on main menu. How can I do this. Please help

I was searching online and didn't find any exact solution to my problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to code in the frontend theme and also in your module to display your display custom attribute on the placement of the category title.

Custom/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="category.view.container">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.heading" template="Example_CategoryHeading::category/heading.phtml" before="category.description"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Turn on the Template path hints and find the phtml file, where you can find the file location attribute to display in the menu title. Remember to override your custom theme or module.

For Template path hints:

1. On the Admin sidebar, go to **Stores > Settings > Configuration**.
2. In the left panel, expand Advanced and choose Developer.
3. Expand Expansion selector in the Debug section and do the following:

[image]

To get the category attribute:

```
$categoryId = 3;
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
echo $category->getName();
echo $category->getData('<attribute_code>');
```

Remember, object manager is not recommended.

In the app/design/frontend/theme vendor/themename/Magento_Catalog/layout/ folder, the file catalog_category_view.xml is responsible for displaying the title. In this xml file, the setPageTitle action method is used, and you can override the category default title according to your requirement.